# How do I properly decorate a `classmethod` with `functools.lru_cache`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, static-methods, python-decorators

I tried to decorate a  `classmethod` with `functools.lru_cache`. My attempt failed:

```
import functools
class K:
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=32)
    @classmethod
    def mthd(i, stryng: str): \
        return stryng

obj = K()
```

The error message comes from `functools.lru_cache`:

```
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

Comment: `classmethod` has to be used last.. which means it has to be at the top of your decorator chain

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A class method is, itself, not callable. (What *is* callable is the object return by the class method's `__get__` method.)

As such, you want the function decorated by `lru_cache` to be turned into a class method instead.

```
@classmethod
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def mthd(cls, stryng: str):
    return stryng
```

Answer (score 6):

The selected answer is totally correct but adding another post. If you want to bind the cache storages to each classes, instead of sharing the single storage to all its subclasses, there is another option [methodtools](https://pypi.org/project/methodtools/)

```py
import functools
import methodtools


class K:
    @classmethod
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=1)
    def mthd(cls, s: str):
        print('functools', s)
        return s

    @methodtools.lru_cache(maxsize=1)  # note that methodtools wraps classmethod
    @classmethod
    def mthd2(cls, s: str):
        print('methodtools', s)
        return s


class L(K):
    pass


K.mthd('1')
L.mthd('2')
K.mthd2('1')
L.mthd2('2')

K.mthd('1')  # functools share the storage
L.mthd('2')
K.mthd2('1')  # methodtools doesn't share the storage
L.mthd2('2')
```

Then the result is

```
$ python example.py
functools 1
functools 2
methodtools 1
methodtools 2
functools 1
functools 2
```